# Different ways to store a 2D map/landscape in XNA

Tags: xna, 2d, maps, procedural-generation, data

I was looking around at this site about eight months ago and wish I saved the location of this topic but I was wondering the different map rendering styles that you can do in XNA.  The one style I looked at was using a text file to pull characters like "X" would be a monster and "O" would be the player.  Is there another way with out an external file that I can put tiles from a sprite sheet to randomly create a map.  Of course when dealing with random buildings I would have certain building designs so that if some one was playing they wouldn't see a building with half a wall missing.

This is for a top down 2D game.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of different ways to store this information. I would suggest using something standard, though. For instance a lot of opensource games use the [TMX map format](https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki/TMX-Map-Format) as used by the [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) editor and several others.

TMX uses XML but can store its data in compressed form, as an array, or using a CSV layout. The storage method is for you to choose in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the above answer Nick Gravelyn makes a very nice library for importing and rendering TMX maps. Takes about 10 lines of code to import it from Tiled and render it.

https://bitbucket.org/nickgravelyn/tiledlib